# How to use CircularProgressBar in flutter

Tags: flutter

[image]I want to show a `CircularProgressBarIndicator` in the flutter on a button click for some seconds and navigate to another page and  loads the current page for some duration on button click and while loading it shows the `CircularProgressBarIndicator`.

Comment: Do you want to load _before_ or _after_ navigating?

Comment: After clicking on button it displays CircularProgressBarIndicator for some seconds then navigate to another page

Comment: And in the second case after clicking on the button it displays CircularProgressBarIndicator for some seconds and then displays the same page

Comment: You need to provide a sample UI mock of what you are looking for.

Comment: after clicking place bids it loads the data of this page and till loading it displays the CircularProgressBarIndicator and after loading all the data it display the same page

Answer (score 0):

Well you can actually achieve this by wrapping your button onPressed function with setState() where you change a variable isLoading to either true or false when you want the CircularProgressIndicator to work. Also, dont forget to call false to stop loader before Navigating to next page because you don't want the user to pop the page and meet a loading spinner. But enough talking since there is a flutter package i always use for that. Check it out at:

> https://pub.dev/packages/modal_progress_hud

I guess the documentation of the package is pretty easy too.

Comment: i have applied that code but the spinner is continuously loading it is not stopping

Comment: Did you call setState after setting isLoading property to false?

Comment: After hot reloading the CircularBar is running continously